# Why all the values in geometry column is POINT Z(long, lat) and not as POINT (long, lat) in a geodataframe?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas

Whenever I open a point shapefile, usually in the geometry column the value will be in the format as follows
`POINT (long, lat)` but while opening some shapefiles I get `POINT Z (long, lat)`. May I know the difference between the geometry values 'POINT Z (long, lat)' and 'POINT (long, lat)'? is it possible to convert them eachother?

Here is my following code in python.

`import geopandas as gpd geo_points = gpd.read_file('.../point_data/groundtruth.shp') geo_points`

I got this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjhDb.png)

But I expect 'POINT (long, lat)' in value of geometry column.

P.S. I also tried by changing the EPSG of the geometry to 4326. But nothing changed. I would be happy to receive any new information you regarding this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

POINT Z means that the coordinates also contain a Z value, so an altitude. Mind that in geopandas this value will be ignored in general, so overlays, area calculation,... all ignore this and just use x and y values.

The Z coordinate value is also visible in the screenshot showing your data: in these examples the Z coördinate values are all between 69 and 70 meter.

You can convert the POINT Z data to POINT data like this:

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point

series_z = geopandas.GeoSeries([Point(1, 1, 1), Point(2, 2, 2), Point(3, 3, 3)])
print(series_z)

series_xy = geopandas.GeoSeries(geopandas.points_from_xy(x=series_z.x, y=series_z.y))
print(series_xy)
```